# How to check if PC is connected to internet via router / switch?

Tags: c#, winforms, switch-statement, router, portforwarding

I want to detect whether my application is connected to internet via router / switch. I have a port forwarding code in C#, which I want to run only when the PC is behind a router / switch ?

Please help.

Comment: By default, you cannot be connected to the Internet without be behind a router... So you need to provide more informations about your question : do you want to know if you're behind a specific router ?
Otherwise, you could just use the [Ping class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: When I connect via a 3G modem. There is no need to forward the port for P2P connection. And when I am connected via router, it need to forward the port.

Comment: As a quick workaround, maybe you can call a server on port 80, check the request source IP and compare it with your local IP: if they match, you're directly connected to the web, otherwise you're behind a router.

Comment: Or can I do it like this...
if (GetLocalIPAddress().StartsWith("192.168") || GetLocalIPAddress().StartsWith("10.0") || GetLocalIPAddress().StartsWith("172.16"))
{
}

Answer (score 2):

The physical router you see is a red herring. Even with your 3G modem, there is almost surely a router somewhere upstream that you are connected to. There's probably one in the cell tower.

I'd approach this by trying to establish the connection *without* port forwarding. If that works, we're good. If that doesn't work, try *with* the port forwarding code.